# When I use `rpm -import`, there get `curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).` error

Tags: centos, rpm

When I use `rpm -import`, there get `curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).` error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
Error：https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org: import read failed(2).
```

my OS is CentOS 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate for https://www.elrepo.org/ is not secure(not trusted), so rpm is rejecting import. If you trust the site download it on local system and then import.